# If any clause when grouping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Doing a Sum() on a column adds up the values in that column based on group by. But lets say I want to sum these values only if all the values are not null or not 0, then I need a clause which checks if any of the values is 0 before it does the sum. How can I implement such a clause?

I'm using sql server 2005.

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: I don't think you can implement this in a simple query.  You'll need to do this in a code: either a stored procedure/function or your application code.  What you could do, of course, is run two queries: one to check whether you have any nulls or 0 values and, if no, then run the second query to sum the values.

Comment: But: 0 + 0 + 2 + 3 = 5 and 2 + 3 = 5 so what's the point (eliminating zeros)?

Comment: @MichałPowaga, reread question. `0+0+2+3 = Exclude this group.`

Comment: No, its 0+2+3=0 and 2+3 = 5 for this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's supose your table schema is:

```
myTable( id, colA, value)
```

Then, one approach is:

```
Select colA, sum(value)
from myTable
group by colA
having count( id ) = count( nullif( value, 0 ))
```

Notice that nullif is a MSSQL server function. YOu should adapt code to your rdbms brand.

**Explanation:**

[count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) aggregate function only count not null values. [Here a counting null values test.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65547/counting-null-values)

Answer (score 1):

You say that 0+2+3=0 for this case. Assuming that NULL+2+3 should also be zero:

```
SELECT GroupField,
    SUM(Value) * MIN(CASE WHEN COALESCE(Value, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM SumNonZero
GROUP BY GroupField
```

The above statement gives this result

```
GroupField   (No column name)
case1        5
case2        0
case3        0
```

with this test data

```
CREATE TABLE SumNonZero (
    GroupField CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO SumNonZero(GroupField, Value)
SELECT 'case1', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'case1', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'case2', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'case2', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'case2', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'case3', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'case3', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'case3', 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to eliminate 0 from a SUM because it wont impact the sum.
But you may want to SUM based on another field:

```
select FIELD, sum(
                  case when(OTHER_FIELD>0) then FIELD 
                       else 0 
                  end) 
from TABLE
group by TABLE
```